# Get the characters from a list of lists

Tags: python, list, chars

I have this example :

```
example=[["hello i am adolf","hi my name is "],["this is a test","i like to play"]]
```

So , I want to get the following array:

```
chars2=[['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'i', ' ', 'a', 'm', ' ', 'a', 'd', 'o', 'l', 'f','h', 'i', ' ', 'm', 'y', ' ', 'n', 'a', 'm', 'e', ' ', 'i', 's'],['t', 'h', 'i', 's', ' ', 'i', 's', ' ', 'a', ' ', 't', 'e', 's', 't', 'i', ' ', 'l', 'i', 'k', 'e', ' ', 't', 'o', ' ', 'p', 'l', 'a', 'y']]
```

I tried this:

```
chars2=[]
for list in example:
    for string in list:
        chars2.extend(string)
```

but i get the following:

```
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'i', ' ', 'a', 'm', ' ', 'a', 'd', 'o', 'l', 'f', 'h', 'i', ' ', 'm', 'y', ' ', 'n', 'a', 'm', 'e', ' ', 'i', 's', ' ', 't', 'h', 'i', 's', ' ', 'i', 's', ' ', 'a', ' ', 't', 'e', 's', 't', 'i', ' ', 'l', 'i', 'k', 'e', ' ', 't', 'o', ' ', 'p', 'l', 'a', 'y']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each `list` in example you need to add another list inside `chars2` , currently you are just extending chars2 directly with each character.

Example -

```
chars2=[]
for list in example:
    a = []
    chars2.append(a)
    for string in list:
        a.extend(string)
```

---

Example/Demo -

```
>>> example=[["hello i am adolf","hi my name is "],["this is a test","i like to play"]]
>>> chars2=[]
>>> for list in example:
...     a = []
...     chars2.append(a)
...     for string in list:
...         a.extend(string)
...
>>> chars2
[['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'i', ' ', 'a', 'm', ' ', 'a', 'd', 'o', 'l', 'f', 'h', 'i', ' ', 'm', 'y', ' ', 'n', 'a', 'm', 'e', ' ', 'i', 's', ' '], ['t', 'h', 'i', 's', ' ', 'i', 's', ' ', 'a', ' ', 't', 'e', 's', 't', 'i', ' ', 'l', 'i', 'k', 'e', ' ', 't', 'o', ' ', 'p', 'l', 'a', 'y']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a simple list comprehension

```
example = [list(item) for sub in example for item in sub]
```

---

Comment: FYI that does not give what the OP has given in *I want to get the following array:* .